# ASP.Net Core HttpClient from Console returns 503 "Service Unavailable"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Problem: HttpClient returns 503 "Service Unavailable" when accessing locally hosted API through console app while it can be accessed successfully using Edge. Am I missing some configurations?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleClient
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting connections");
            for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            {

                var result = await Client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5100/api/contacts");
                //var result = await Client.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/");
                Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Connections done");
        }
    }
}
```

--- build ---

dotnet build

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0-preview-20064-06+86d9494e4 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

...

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

sample output: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64z6d.png)

[clear headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udd3W.png)

Comment: in your api side, please enable debug level log and check if there is any error in log

Comment: What about if you try add `Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));` before you calling `GetAsync`?

Comment: Even if I cleared the header, still it is error.

Comment: @ElendilZheng-MSFT I think API is working properly. As shown in the screenshots, it can be displayed in Edge. (even in firefox, chrome and postman)

Comment: @SelimYıldız I added screenshots. Please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udd3W.png

Comment: Did you start your .net core hosted instance or IIS website/apppool prior to executing the Get to localhost:5100?

Comment: @StinkyTowel I tried the following: (1) 2 start-up project (API and Console - stated above) (2) API as separate solution/project started separately (3) Published to IIS. All of these 3 scenarios output the same error. *I am sure that API is working properly because it is properly accessed using Edge/Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. The cause is the Antivirus firewall.
After disabling, I was able to access successfully.

Comment: Please can you be specific on the changes you made? I am facing the same issue.